# Spring controller get empty object

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, jspx

I'm sending an object to spring controller via jsp form.

JSP:

```
<form:form modelAttribute="uploadItem" action="/uploadObject" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<form:input path="fileData" accept="audio/mpeg" type="file" id="file-upload" name="file-upload" />

<form:input type="text" path="title" id="upload-title" name="upload-title"/>

<input type="image" src="..." alt="Upload"/>

</form:form>
```

ModelService:

```
 public void fillUploadMelodyModel(Model model) {
    fillAdminRootModel(model);
    model.addAttribute("uploadItem", new UploadedItem());
}
```

UploadedItem:

```
public class UploadedItem {
  private CommonsMultipartFile fileData;
  private String title;
}
```

Controller:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/uploadObject", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String doUpload(UploadedItem uploadItem, BindingResult result, Principal principal) {
//at this point I get an empty object (null null values)
}
```

What is the problem? How to pass object to controller in jsp?

Comment: did you add to the web.xml the configuration to upload files? the max file size?

Comment: i use spring boot without web.xml

Comment: Remove the `name` attribute from your `form` elements and add `@ModelAttribute` to your method parameter.

Comment: Then you need this.  spring.http.multipart.maxFileSize=10Mb

Comment: I did the steps above - it didn't help

Comment: to make easier to read, i added the response as solution, let me know if works, for me does

Comment: For this way I should send multimedia data with url request which seems not correct

Comment: Is the same action, you are using POST to send a file, whatever you store in that file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing then your controller like this

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/uploadObject", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String doUpload(UploadedItem uploadItem, 
                      BindingResult result, 
                      @RequestParam("fileData") MultipartFile file,
                      @RequestParam("title") String title,
                      Principal principal) {
//Here you should receive your parameters
}
```

Comment: Could make it a little shorter with this instead: `@PostMapping("/uploadObject")`

Comment: @bphilipnyc nice i didnt use that annotation yest but i will :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the names you have used for the file (file-upload) and title (upload-title) are not in sync with your domain object attribute names. Change your names to fileData and title in your Jsp page.